# Add small address book in iphone app

Tags: iphone

I am making a medication based application in which I want to add small address book which will store doctor's information. Can I add address book in iphone application? If someone has idea please help me.

Thanks alot.

Comment: i guess you need to use sqlite Database

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to store a couple of addresses you could also consider storing and loading the data from a property list. They're great for storing small amounts of data and you don't have to go through the mess of configuring Core Data and your persistence class.